# Combine two Media fields in Product types and Product variation types

Tags: views, entities, commerce

i'm drupal beginner, i install drupal 8 commerce 2, i create a media field in Product types and create another media field Product variation types also.

when i create new product, i want to give user can upload global images, and also upload different color-type images when user create their own products. At the same time, display those images in one photo gallery.

How can i combine all the upload images show in one photo gallery, at the same time the user change different colors, the photo gallery can only show global images and product's color image? (i'm using Juicebox to display the product image.) Or Any suggestion on other modules can do this. Plz help!!

[image: In Drupal cms i have two media input fields]
[image: Output is two photo gallery coming out, i want combine both to one photo gallery]

Comment: So each user account has its own photo gallery, and you want to allow each user to configure settings for the user's gallery?

Comment: @PatrickKenny Sorry, My English not good, I mean i have two different media fields setup in different types, i want combine data and show in one Juicebox gallery.